# How to connect PG Admin to PostgreSQL on Azure?

Tags: postgresql, azure, pgadmin

I am looking to connect my existing PostgreSQL instance on Azure to PG-Admin. Following the advice [here](https://www.sqlshack.com/accessing-azure-database-for-postgresql-using-pgadmin/), however I get a `Unable to connect to server: could not translate host name` error. To the best of my knowledge, the host name should be correct. I am taking it from the overview page on Azure, and can confirm it follows the right format of "servername.postgres.database.azure.com". I have also confirmed that that password and usernames are correct, and SSL Mode is set to require (see screenshot, with dummy variables).

[image]

In addition, I have tried this on a seperate database in Azure with the same result. No doubt its a mistake I'm making with the hostname/address field in PG-Admin, but I've no idea how to correct.

Comment: In the Azure Portal, check the firewall settings for your Postgresql DB resource. Check other possible root causes for connection failures, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/single-server/how-to-troubleshoot-common-connection-issues

Answer (score 2):

Prerequisites for connecting PostgreSQL server

1. Connectivity method: public if we allow for all traffic, private if we restrict traffic via VNet.
2. Add the IP address where PgAdmin4 is running to the firewall rule.

**Step1:**
Created a new PostgreSQL server
[image]

**Step2:**
Updated network firewall setting as fallows and saved
[image]

**Verification from PgAdmin4**

**Step1:**
copy the server's name, user and password from the server setting
[image]

**Step2:**
Open PgAdmin4 portal and click on register server information
[image]

**On General Tab, enter**
- Name:  "Any Name"
[image]

**On Connection Tab:**

- HostName : "Server Name from the portal"
- User Name: "Server admin login name from portal"
- Password: "Enter Admin Password"
- Database: "Enter DB name else keep same name"

[image]

**On SSL Tab:**

- Keep **SSL Mode** as "**Require**" and click on SAVE
  [image]

**Upon Save.**
[image]

**NOTE: Make sure firewall should allow and SSL should be Require.**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I probably should have mentioned this in the original post but  I'm connecting via a private Vnet. As such, in step 2 I don't have the option of specifying an IP address.